# How make jQuery UI Dialog be draggable outside of viewpoint too?

Tags: jquery-ui

For now, it's only draggable within viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, it's part of the page/frame it's in.  If this *were* allowed, you'd see advertisements outside the frame as well :)

If you want to drag it outside of the scrolled view in the page, that's the default behavior, [you can test it here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Nick Craver, I think you did not understand me. If you set up a simple div element to be draggable, you could drag it beyond the viewpoint. But that just doesn't work you use the dialog. What ads are you talking about?